# update status field of a row in a table on url click in cake php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have created a quotations module in cake php. In the index.ctp view I need to add a link to approve the quotation. initialy I have set the quotation as pending . So when the user visits the index.ctp, He will be able to view all the quotation that are pending and approved. My only issue is I cannot update the status to approved when clicking the approve url

```
public function update($id) {   
            $this->Quotation->id = $id;
            $this->request->is(array('post', 'put'));  
            $data = array(
            'Quotation' => array(
                    'Quot_id'          =>    $id,
                    'status'   =>    'Approved'
           )
    );
            $this->Quotation->save( $data, false, array('status'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Approve'), array('action' => 'update', $quotation['Quotation']['Quot_id']), array(), __('Are you sure you want to Approve # %s?', $quotation['Quotation']['Quot_id']));
?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'id' to fieldList array:

```
$this->Quotation->save( $data, false, array('id','status'));
```

Comment: Thanks its working , I added the Quot_id instead of id in the code u mentioned, Its working . Thanks :)